Preview for AppEntity in Spotlight search result
I have app with AppEntity indexed to be shown in Spotlight search results. Can I somehow control, how my data is presented there?
What I would like to know:

If I can show menu with submenu when performing long press on my entity in Spotlight? I would like to have the same effect, as you can see for Contact search result, when given contact has two emails. In such case, after performing long press you can see "Message" menu option with two suboptions for each email from contact
Can I show custom view in result preview after long press on my entity in Spotlight? I would like to have the same effect, as you can see for Safari search result (search string found on some page in Safari). When you long press on such result, you can see page preview being loaded.
Can I block showing preview view after long press on my entity in Spotlight? If there is nothing to show in preview, I would like to block it - do not have expanded, empty preview view?

